# Atmel M90E26 energy meter

Tags: energy, power-meter

[Datasheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjZ_5-Qk-XVAhWJaVAKHd4jDMYQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.atmel.com%2Fimages%2FAtmel-46002-SE-M90E26-Datasheet.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGD71iLUyfMmFmybnhmeFG0i0hx9g)

[Application Note](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiV86L4lOXVAhUCU1AKHfqsBUEQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.atmel.com%2FImages%2FAtmel-46102-SE-M90E26-ApplicationNote.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFzHg8nk8bVcZuUYhLJT96jDbB__w)

I'm working with the atmel m90e26 IC. Its energy is numerically pulse_based, but I do not know what the relationship between energy and pulse is in this IC. There's a  parameter named MC=3200 imp/kWh in the application note I attached it with the datasheet. Maybe this parameter is related to my problem.

What the relationship between energy and pulse is in this IC?

Answer (score -1):

Once you make an energy meter, it won't directly give you the accurate reading of 3200 impulses per kWh. You need to calibrate each energy meter circuits individually against a standard meter.

For your chip (M90E26), it requires writing to some calibration registers. Check section 3 of your document.

If this calibration process looks too complicated to you, you can go for simpler chips where calibration requires shorting of binary ladder resistors on the voltage sampling channel. Example of such an IC - BL0921.

Comment: thanks. i did some of the calibration but  i know nothing about what MC is and how to calculate it.could you please explain more ??

Answer (score -1):

Your component will pulse 3,200 times, over the course of a KWh.  If it's pulsed 1600 times, that's 0.5KWh.

Conversion from KWh to energy is possible, but if you're building an energy meter you don't want to record energy.  You want Power over time, measured in KWh... Because that's what they bill you for.

Rational: I have built an almost identical project.

Comment: No, you are billed for **energy** you use, and kWh **is** energy. You do not want power over time, and kWh is power **times** time.

Comment: I'm billed for KWh.  More to point, 1 energy is measured in Jules, not Watts.   W=1J per second.  1Wh is 1J every second for an hour, or 3600J.  While you can move between energy and work done over time, why bother?  Your actual bill is in KWh, aka "units".

Comment: Of course you are billed in kWh because **it is energy** and you are billed for the amount of **energy** you consume. Energy is not measured in "Jules". The SI unit for energy is the joule. The SI unit symbol for the prefix kilo is k. The letter K is the SI unit symbol for thermodynamic temperature.

Comment: That's what you get for commenting on a phone with autocorrect.

Comment: I don't understand your point. Are you acknowledging the mistake and blaming it on your phone?

Comment: I blame auto-correct for the misspelt unit.  I repeat that the Watt, or Watt Hour,. is not the unit of energy, which you've correctly noted is the joule.  There is a strong relationship, but they are not the same.  But leaving this discussion, because it's not providing value to anyone.

Comment: Don't confuse a **quantity** with a **unit**. A watt is a unit of the quantity power, and it happens to be the SI standard unit. The joule is the SI standard unit of the quantity energy, but there are other units used for energy and they include the electron-volt, the BTU, the erg, the calorie, the therm, **and the watt hour**. See NIST Special Publication 811. And this discussion **is** providing value if it corrects incorrect statements.